# Symfony3 - Validation of an embedded form

Tags: forms, symfony, validation, constraints

I have an embedded form like this:

-> Parent (class)

|---> Attribute 1 (collection) : children (class) : required

.......|-----> Attribute 1 : child_name (string) : required

.......|-----> Attribute 2 : child_description (string) : required

I want, when I send the form:

1. There is at least one parent object sent (I mean the children attribute contains at least one row of (child_name and child_description)

If the data received will be like this :

- `parent[children][__name__][child_name]=value1&parent[children][__name__][child_description]=value2`

Where **name** is the iteration in the ArrayCollection of the attribute children

So when we send two children in the form, we get this data:

- `parent[children][0][child_name]=value1&parent[children][0][child_description]=value2&parent[children][1][child_name]=value3&parent[children][1][child_description]=value4`

I want that:

2. If the user will send only nothing (empty form), he gets an error that the atribute children is required.
3. If the user will send only the child_name (or the child_description) value, he gets an error that the child_description (or the child_name) is also required. I mean if he doesn't event send the varaible child_name (or child_description) in the form like this:

   - `parent[children][__name__][child_name]=value1 (without the name and the value of the variable parent[children][__name__][child_description])`

I tried to validate this form from the Entity But I got some problems.

In the Parent Entity class:

```
/**
 * Parent
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="parent")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Parent
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Error", groups={"Creation"})
     * @Assert\NotNull(message="Error", groups={"Creation"}))
     * @Assert\Count(
     *      min = 1,
     *      minMessage = "Error",
     *      groups={"Creation"}
     * )
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Children", mappedBy="parent", cascade={"ALL"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    protected $children;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->children = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add child
     *
     * @param Child $child
     * @return children
     */
    public function addChild(Child $child)
    {
        $this->children[] = $child;
        $child->setParent($this);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove child
     *
     * @param Child $child
     */
    public function removeChild(Child $child)
    {
        $this->children->removeElement($child);
    }

    public function getChildren()
    {
        return $this->children;
    }

    /**
     * Get id.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Then, the Child Entity class:

```
/**
 * Child
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="child")
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"child_name","child_description"},
 *     message="already registred"
 * )
 */
class Child
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Parent
     */
    private $parent;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(name="child_name", type="string", length=255 )
         *
         * Assert\NotBlank(message="empty", groups={"Creation"})
         * Assert\NotNull(message="null", groups={"Creation"})
         * @Assert\Length(
         *     min=3,
         *     minMessage="too short",
         *     groups={"Creation"}
         * )
         * @Assert\Type(
         *     type="string",
         *     message="you need a string",
         *     groups={"Creation"}
         * )
         */
        private $child_name;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(name="child_description", type="string", length=255 )
         *
         * Assert\NotBlank(message="empty", groups={"Creation"})
         * Assert\NotNull(message="null", groups={"Creation"})
         * @Assert\Length(
         *     min=3,
         *     minMessage="too short",
         *     groups={"Creation"}
         * )
         * @Assert\Type(
         *     type="string",
         *     message="you need a string",
         *     groups={"Creation"}
         * )
         */
        private $child_description;

    public function __construct()
    {}

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set childName
     *
     * @param string $childName
     *
     * @return Child
     */
    public function setChildName($childName)
    {
        $this->child_name = $childName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get childName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getChildName()
    {
        return $this->child_name;
    }

    /**
     * Set childDescription
     *
     * @param string $childDescription
     *
     * @return Child
     */
    public function setChildDescription($childDescription)
    {
        $this->child_description = $childDescription;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get childDescription
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->child_description ;
    }
```

In the Controller class:

```
public function postChildrenAction(Request $request)
{
    $result = new Parent();
    $em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    $form = $this->createForm(ParentType::class, $result, array(
            'validation_groups' => array('Creation', 'Default'),
    ));
    $form->submit($request->request->get($form->getName()));
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        //persistance
    }
}
```

In the ParentType class :

```
class ParentType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('children', CollectionType::class,array(
                'entry_type' => ChildType::class,
                'required'=> true,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete'  => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'constraints' => array(new Valid()), // __LINE_A__
                'entry_options' => array(
                        'validation_groups' => $options['validation_groups'],
                        'required'=> true,
                ),
        ));

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => 'Path\NameBundle\Entity\Parent',
            'csrf_protection' => false,
            'validation_groups' => array('Creation', 'Default'),
            'cascade_validation' => true,
            'error_bubbling' => false,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And finally the ChildType:

```
class ChildType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('child_name',TextType::class,array('required'=> true,'validation_groups'=>$options['validation_groups']));
        $builder->add('child_description',TextType::class,array('required'=> true,'validation_groups'=>$options['validation_groups']));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => 'Path\NameBundle\Entity\Child',
            'csrf_protection' => false,
            'validation_groups' => array('Creation', 'Default'),
            'cascade_validation' => true,
            'error_bubbling' => false,
        ]);
    }
}
```

4. The first problem is in the Parent Entity class: when I remove the Assert\Count() constraint from the children attribute, the validation will succeed. So why the constraints NotBlank and NotNull doesn't work ?
5. If I comment the line `'constraints' => array(new Valid())` (`__LINE_A__`) in the ParentType, the constraint UniqueEntity of ChildType will not work. Why ?
6. None of the `'required' => true` options in the ParentType and ChildType worked. When I send only the child name without a description (or the inverse), I got an SQL error saying that there is a null value of the description.
7. When the form is empty the validation will succeed but I need to get an error when some data is missing (for the child object or the parent object).
8. The groups option from the Parent/Child Entity classes doesn't work if the form is sent with a missing variable even when I enable `'cascade_validation' => true`.

This is too hard.

And to finish with this post, I want to know :

9. The constraints that we define in the Entity classes aren't the ones that validates the form ? Because when I create the same constraints in validation.yml (using NotBlank with child_name and child_description) the validation works fine and fails if there is a missing variable/data.

### Thank you even by answering me to one of these questions.

Comment: the question is huge

Comment: Yes but the principal question remains about the question number 9. I don't know why the constraints in the Entity classes and in the form Type classes doesn't work but in the validation.yml worked fine ? Am I supposed to write the same validation constraints in EntityType and copy the same conditions in the validation.yml ? This doesn't make any sense.